# Open Delegate fails when trying to access Int or DateTime property

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have been testing out using delegates instead of reflection for some object sorting and it was working good for string properties, but if I try an Int (or DateTime) it fails and throws

> Error binding to target method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sample = new SampleClass() { Num = 13, Text = "Sample" };

        Console.WriteLine(ReadProp(sample,"Text")); //Works
        Console.WriteLine(ReadProp(sample, "classProp")); //Works
        Console.WriteLine(ReadProp(sample, "Num")); //Throws 'Error binding to target method.'
    }

    //Use a Delegate to improve speed of accessing property instead of reflection
    static object ReadProp(SampleClass obj, string propName)
    {
        var method = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetGetMethod();
        var getForProp = (Func<SampleClass, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<SampleClass, object>), null, method);
        return getForProp(obj);
    }
}

//A sample class for illustration purposes
class SampleClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public SampleClass classProp { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: **Why does it work for strings or other classes but not for Int or DateTime?**

I can see that if I change my `Func<SampleClass, object>` to `Func<SampleClass, int>` it will then work for my Int but I expected object would work for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it work for strings or other classes but not for Int or DateTime?

Because a method which returns an `int` *isn't* a method which returns an `object` reference. There has to be a boxing conversion - so something's got to do that, and `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is trying to provide a delegate which *just* invokes the delegate and returns the result, with no value conversion involved.

It's slightly painful to do, but basically I suspect you should *either* be building a `Func` with an appropriate return value and using that directly *or* you should go via a wrapper delegate which calls the "real" delegate and boxes the result.

(Note that in your sample code, you're creating the delegate each time, which is going to be no faster than reflection. Hopefully your real code is more sensible :)

If you look at [this code from `protobuf-csharp-port`](http://protobuf-csharp-port.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/src/ProtocolBuffers/FieldAccess/ReflectionUtil.cs) you'll see I've got a method to do exactly this - a lambda expression calls the strongly-typed delegate, and then uses the implicit conversion to `object` (boxing where necessary) to provide the value. You should be able to use something very similar. However, if you're sorting do you really *want* a `Func<T, object>`? If you use a strongly-typed delegate instead, you may be able to avoid all this boxing.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look at that. In my case I do not know the return type at design time and would have to determine the property return type at runtime

Comment: @deepee1: That's exactly what the code in the link does - you give it a `MethodInfo`, it gives you a `Func<T, object>`. The generic method is invoked via reflection when creating the delegate.

Comment: yes, I am reading now, this looks like the missing piece to my puzzle, thanks. The key in your description above was "just invokes the delegate and returns the result, with no value conversion involved." which makes more sense to me now.

Comment: Worked well using your tricks in `CreateUpcastDelegate` and `CreateUpcastDelegateImpl` methods. Thanks much.